# Express 4 define a new route inside a app.use route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a express nodejs app, and I'm, trying to use "dynamic routes" inside another route.

I have:

```
....
app.use('/test/:id',
   function(req,res,next) {         
     app.use('/foo', static(path.join(__dirname, 'photos/'+req.params.id)));
     res.redirect('/foo/img1.jpg');
   }
);
```

The res.redirect return "Not found" even if the file is present in the directory.

I need this to serve static image photo file from a directory with sub-dir of album of photos, in a dynamic way, so I can upload new sub-dir without rewriting the routes in express.

By the way, I'm using https://github.com/timmydoza/express-photo-gallery and I'm trying to modify it to my needs.

Thank you

**UPDATED**:

I forget that if I extract the `app.use('/foo'....` outside the `app.use('/test/:id'...` the image is found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
  express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'photos/' + req.params.id ))
  ^^^^^^^
```

Instead of:

```
 static( path.join( __dirname, 'photos/' + req.params.id ))
```

And don't forget to import `path` module:

```
 const path = require("path");
```

Remember that all paths `photos/{id}` should be created before